# How do I sort by taxonomy term parent, and then by post date?

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms

I have the following taxonomy structure:

Locations

- Group 1

  - Location 1
  - Location 2
- Group 2

  - Location 3
  - Location 4
- Group 3

  - Location 5
  - Location 6

Pieces of content are being posted to the site, and each piece of content has a location and a post date associated with it.  When the view is displayed, how can the results be grouped by parent term ID (group 1-3), and then grouped by post date within each group?

I've tried using the "taxonomy term: name" sort criterion, but then adding the "content: post-date" criterion seems to have no effect.

Comment: Is your list of Groups small or large?  Is it static?  I can think of a round-about way to do this, but it won't be a good solution unless the parent terms are pretty static.  :-(

Answer (score 2):

I think I found a way to do this--I added the "content: taxonomy terms on node" and "taxonomy term: parent term" relationships to the view.

The key is the "taxonomy term: name" criterion has a checkbox where I selected "parent", which appears only after you add the relationship.  I added the post-date sort criteria after that, and it appears to be working the way I want.

Comment: I recently discovered that the sort works better if you *require* the relationship because it uses inner joins instead of left joins.

Answer (score 0):

For really simple sorting, such as it's outlined in the question it's easy but took me a while to find it (*no* relationships needed):

1. Add taxonomy term as a field and exclude it from the display.

   Make sure you have the title field still in the display.
2. Then under **Format**, *click on "settings"* to the right of "format:"
3. Under "Grouping field Nr.1" choose the taxonomy term field.

Now all your content should be grouped according to their respective term:

- Term Name 1

  - Item 1 Title
  - Item 2 Title
- Term Name 2

  - Item 3 Title
  - Item 4 Title
- Term Name 3

  - Item 5 Title
  - Item 6 Title